# ¿Métodos efectivos para actualizar la caché al hacer cambios en los ficheros css?

Tags: css, .htaccess

me gustaría saber si hay algo efectivo para actualizar la caché de un fichero **css** cuando realices algún cambio.

Actualmente tengo activada la caché para los ficheros **css** de mi web mediante el **.htaccess**, pero al realizar algún cambio, me veo obligado a borrar la caché del navegador para que sean visibles, pero los visitantes generalmente no hacen eso.

Fichero .htaccess que guarda en caché ciertos elementos de la página:

## Cache-control headers

```
# 1 SEMANA
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|xml|txt|css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Y esta es la forma con la que actualmente voy usando para que se vean los cambios que realizo en el css:

```
<link href="/css/style.css?version=1.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Pero me resulta algo incómodo tener que modificar siempre la variable "ficticia" **"?version=1.1"** a mano.

He pensado que podría hacerse con **php**, pero lo mismo podría afectar el rendimiento de la página.

He estado investigando y he encontrado cosas de hace unos *7 años*, no sé si ha salido algo nuevo en estos años, ¿cómo lo hacéis vosotros?

Comment: ¿Cómo guardas el CSS en la caché mediante .htaccess?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he editado el mensaje con más información. Muchas gracias.